# Using price contraints or a function in Postgres for "money" type?

Tags: postgresql, currency

I'm trying to make sure all the sales prices in my postgres database end in either .99 or .00.

If the price is 34.00, I'd like the database to leave it alone.  If the price is something like 34.34 I'd like it to be changed to 34.99.

Can this be done entirely inside of postgres, with a function, or some system of contraints?  Just want to make sure it's possible before I start hammering away at it.

Comment: Yes this is possible in a trigger. But I wouldn't use the `money` data type. Use `numeric` instead. The money type has too many quirks to be useful.

Comment: What are some of the quirks?

Comment: For one: the currency symbol displayed along with it depends on the client's configuration. So one user could see `19.99€` another might see `$19.99`. And you can't have more then two fractional places if I'm not mistaken. It was actually deprecated in older versions. http://postgresql.nabble.com/Money-data-type-Deprecated-td1903207.html but still seems rather useless to me. `numeric` is much better and clearer

Comment: Another quirk is that the JDBC driver can only return `money` values as strings due to the embedded currency symbol. So if you are using Java, `money` is essentially unusable